# asp:SqlDataSource SelectCommand property does not persist when paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView (gvPart)` with a `SqlDataSource (sdsParts)` as its data source. On `gvPart`, I have the property `AllowPaging="true"`. I also have a `TextBox (txtPartSearch)` and a `Button` that are used to enter and exectue a search through `gvPart`. To do this, I have the following in code behind:

```
protected void partSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = txtPartSearch.Text;
    string selectCmd = "SELECT ... WHERE partnum LIKE '" + query + "%' ... "; // I have cut out most of the statement for clarity
    sdsParts.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
    gvPart.DataBind();
}
```

The intent of this is to allow the user to enter a part number, and have `gvPart` display only parts that match the query instead of the entire list.

The first page of `gvPart` after the above method is as expected. However, if this select statement results in more than one page in `gvPart`, clicking page 2 in the footer will show the second page, but the data will be from page 2 of the original data (that is, the data that was initially pulled before the search, with the default `SelectCommand` in `sdsParts`).

It seems like paging "resets" the `SqlDataSource` and uses the `SelectCommand` that is written in Default.aspx, regardless of any `sdsParts.SelectCommand = selectCmd` statement.

I have tried leaving a `SelectCommand` completely out, so that `sdsParts` looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsParts" runat="server" ConnectionString="..." />
```

and then adding the default one in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string selectCmd = "SELECT ... ";
        sdsParts.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
        gvPart.DataBind();
    }
}
```

but then clicking on another page in `gvPart` makes it blank, as if `SelectCommand=""`.

Why does the `SelectCommand` of `sdsParts` "reset," and how can I fix/avoid this?

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

I have solved my problem. For those of you coming here with the same problem, click here for an explanation and suggestion for a workaround.

**EDIT** Moved my above solution to an answer for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQLDataSource` does not maintain any new `SelectCommand`s for security purposes. Thus, the `SelectCommand` property will revert to its original value as coded in the `.aspx` file. A possible solution is to use the `Session` variables like so:

```
protected void partSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = txtPartSearch.Text;
    string selectCmd = "SELECT ... WHERE partnum LIKE '" + query + "%' ... ";
    sdsParts.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
    Session["select"] = selectCmd;
}
```

And in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["select"] != null)
        sdsParts.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
    else
        sdsParts.SelectCommand = "SELECT ... "; //some default command
}
```

[Click here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105069/sqldatasource-selectcommand-not-persisting-on-postback) for a bit more info and to see the location of my solution.

**NOTE:** my method of generating the select statement above is not recommended, as it invites SQL injection attacks. It is recommended to use the [`SqlDataSource Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you changing the SelectCommand of a SqlDataSource in the code behind?  Put it in the control.

Second of all, your code is subject to SQL Injection attacks, please don't concatenate user supplied data into your TSQL... EVER.

For an example, and a quick lesson in pain, go run your program and type in the following for a part number `';DROP TABLE PARTS;'`, then after you are done crying, and if your boss doesn't fire you, change your code.

Comment: I am new to a lot of this, and I do not know how I would avoid such an attack. What steps should I take to prevent one?

Comment: Never concatenate strings together (especially data from a user) that you then pass off to a database.

Comment: You should have in your SqlDataSource a SelectCommand that looks like: `SELECT ... FROM Parts WHERE partnum LIKE @partnum` then create a SqlParameter (Probably ControlParameter) called partnum.

Comment: I will do that then. Also, I know that this does not necessarily constitute a safe solution, but the `MaxLength` of the input text box is 8. There's not a whole lot that can be done in 8 characters to mess everything up

Comment: If you want to have the gridview autobind to the control called txtPartSearch, then create the ControlParameter in the SqlDataSource, tell it to pull the value from txtPartSearch, and don't convert emptystrings to null.  Set the grid's datasource property to the id of your SqlDataSource, and REMOVE ALL YOUR CODE-BEHIND.  It'll all happen for you.

Comment: MaxLength is a client-side validation only.  It's trivial to bypass it.  And, it's best if you get in the habit to never ever do what you did anyhow.  I like to tell people there is NEVER a reason to do that.  Not a legitimate reason anyhow.

Comment: Sorry, in your case, you probably want a SelectCommand like: `SELECT ... FROM Parts WHERE partnum LIKE @partnum+'%'`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will put it to use, and remember this for future reference